# What is the best way to take a WKB value in SQL Server Management Studio and create a PostGIS geometry in PGAdmin III?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql-server, pgadmin-3

Normally, I would just use WKT strings but I'm investigating some possible geometry weirdness with the Text methods in SQL Server. I would like to copy/paste the WKB values from the SQL Server Management Studio data grid and paste into PGAdminIII  SQL Editor.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bit simpler than that.  PostGIS natively understands HEX.

I think you can do this -- here is a string I got from SQL Server STAsBinary() output (after stripping off the 0x)

SELECT '0101000000000000000000F03F0000000000000040'::geometry;

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out that one of my earlier approaches would have worked, but I had a typo in my  postgres query.

1. Right-click and copy the binary hex string from SQL Server
   Management Studio.
2. Paste into a string in the PG Admin III SQL Editor window.
3. Delete the "0x" at the beginning of the string.
4. Wrap that value with a `decode`.
5. Now ST_GeomFromWKB has WKB.

   `SELECT ST_GeomFromWKB(decode('<Paste Hex String Here>', 'hex'),0));`